# AngularJS input slow to fill

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an AngularJS app with a `ng-repeat`. This `ng-repeat` displays only about 60 watchers (the list of `ng-repeat` contains quite big JSON objects though). In the same page I have an input. When I try to write inside this input, it is very slow (displays one letter every second).

I tried to optimize as much as possible but the inputs in my whole app are slow. If I disable the `ng-repeat`, the inputs goes back to normal speed.

Can someone explain to me why inputs are slow? And if I can solve this problem?

Comment: first you should try with `track by $index` does it makes any difference in performance

Comment: maybe share some code?

Comment: Yes! `ng-repeat` is fast to display and I followed all the recommendation to make it as fast as possible (`track by`, `limitTo` etc...)

Comment: @Mikey The problem is that the app is very complex and I already tried to reproduce it in a simple plunker but without success. I just want to understand what could make the input slow...

Comment: @ncohen Ok. No worries. What do you mean with 60 watchers. Is that some sort of realtime database connection.

Comment: @Mikey yes, I'm using PouchDB to sync my local DB with the remote DB. Each time a user makes a change, it changes everywhere (in all users) therefore the list comes from the local DB and is updated each time a change occurs. I'm just surprised inputs can be affected by ng-repeat...

Comment: @ncohen Ah ok, there is your problem I think...Probably 60 watchers on pretty large data consumes a lot of RAM, think of it this way: to maintain a realtime connection pouch reserves a piece of RAM. Can you check if your RAM is highly loaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82431/discussion-between-ncohen-and-mikey).

Comment: Do you try to do profiling on the page to see if what process that causing cpu overhead - chrome dev tools ? If the issue is with ng-repeat then it is most likely caused by DOM rebuilding so better to understand how input & ng-repeat watch object is connected. Ben Nadel provide a nice guide regarding ng-repeat http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2443-rendering-dom-elements-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm